# defmulti não localiza defmethod em outr namespace

Tags: clojure

Criei um projeto em clojure para validar a feature de defmulti com implementações de defmethod em outros namespace. No entanto ao executar o projeto o dispatcher do defmulti não localiza a implementação correta.

[url do projeto no git](https://github.com/Angelicogfa/multi-metodos)

> Implementação

```
(ns multi-metodos.executar)

(defmulti run :tipo)
```

```
(ns multi-metodos.sms
  (:require [multi-metodos.executar :as exe]))

(defmethod exe/run :default [_]
  (println "default"))
```

```
(ns multi-metodos.notificacao
  (:require [multi-metodos.executar :as exe]))

(defmethod exe/run :notificacao [_]
  (println "Enviando notificacao"))
```

```
(ns multi-metodos.email
  (:require [multi-metodos.executar :as exe]))

(defmethod exe/run :email [_]
  (println "Enviando email"))
```

```
(ns multi-metodos.core
  (:require [multi-metodos.executar :as exe]))

(defn -main []
  (println "Ola")
  (exe/run {:tipo :email}))
```

> erro gerado:

```
Exception in thread "main" Syntax error compiling at (C:\Users\guilherme.angelico\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init7125751530945241762.clj:1:121).
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7647)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7573)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:452)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:454)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:454)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:485)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:519)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:516)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:598)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:561)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No method in multimethod 'run' for dispatch value: :email
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.getFn(MultiFn.java:156)
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:229)
    at multi_metodos.core$_main.invokeStatic(core.clj:6)
    at multi_metodos.core$_main.invoke(core.clj:4)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:380)
    at user$eval140.invokeStatic(form-init7125751530945241762.clj:1)
    at user$eval140.invoke(form-init7125751530945241762.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7176)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7166)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1):

*IIsso foi traduzido usando o Google Translate. Peço desculpas se está quebrado Português*

Você precisa garantir que o `multi-metodos.email` é carregado em algum momento. O arquivo de email nunca é carregado, então `(defmethod exe/run :email [_] . . .)` nunca é executado.

Você precisará importar o arquivo de email para que isso funcione. Admito que não uso multi-métodos com muita frequência, então não sei a melhor maneira de configurar isso. No entanto, ele só pode ser remediado importando o arquivo de email:

```
(ns multi-metodos.core
  (:require [multi-metodos.executar :as exe]
            [multi-metodos.email]))  ; Verifique se está carregado

(defn -main []
  (println "Ola")
  (exe/run {:tipo :email}))
```